# YACC or Bison Action Variables positional max value

Tags: yacc

In YACC and other Yacc like programs. There are action positional variables for the current parsed group of tokens. I might want to process some csv file input that the number of columns changes for unknown reasons. With my rules quoted_strings and numbers can be one or more instances found.

```
rule : DATE_TOKEN QUOTED_NUMBERS q_string numbers { printf(..... $1,$2....}

q_string
    : QUOTED_STRING
    | QUOTED_STRING q_string
    ;

numbers
    : number numbers
    | number
    ;

number
    : INT_VALUE
    | FLOAT_VALUE
    ;
```

Actions can be added to do things with what ever has been parsed as is

```
{ printf("%s %s %s \n",$<string>1, $<string>1, $<string>1); }
```

Is there a runtime macro, constuct or variable that tells me how many tokens have been read so that I can write a loop to print all token values?

What is $max

Answer (score 2):

The `$n` variables in a bison action refer to right-hand side symbols, not to tokens. If the corresponding rhs object is a non-terminal, `$n` refers to that non-terminal's semantic value, which was set by assigning to `$$` in the semantic action of that nonterminal.

So if there are five symbols on the right-hand side of a rule, then you can use `$1` through `$5`. There is no variable notation which allows you to refer to the "nth" symbol.